# jQuery function as parameter of other jQuery function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been reading several similar questions about this, but I can't get it to work. I have a scroll detection function in jQuery, which I want to have 3 parameters:

```
function scroll_detection(box_selector, trigger_offset, the_animation){
     //something here
     the_animation();
}
```

Where the_animation is a function that will be called like this:

```
scroll_detection("section", .8, function(){
     //stuff here
});
```

The problem is, when I add the function, the animation do not run anymore.

This code works perfectly:

```
function scroll_detection(duration, box_selector, element_selector, ease, trigger_offset ){
        var effect_offset = Math.floor($(window).height() * trigger_offset);
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            $(box_selector).each(function() {
                var post = $(this);
                var position = post.position().top - ($(window).scrollTop() + effect_offset);               
                if (position <= 0) {
                    $(this).find(element_selector).animate( { marginLeft: "0" }, duration, ease );
                } 
            });        
        });
    }

    scroll_detection(2000, "section", ".section-title", "easeOutBack", .8);
    scroll_detection(3000, ".article-wrap", ".article-title", "easeOutBounce", .7);
```

But this does not:

```
function scroll_detection(the_animation, box_selector, trigger_offset ){
        var effect_offset = Math.floor($(window).height() * trigger_offset);
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            $(box_selector).each(function() {
                var post = $(this);
                var position = post.position().top - ($(window).scrollTop() + effect_offset);               
                if (position <= 0) {
                    the_animation();
                } 
            });        
        });
    }

    scroll_detection( function(){
        $(this).find(".section-title").animate( { marginLeft: "0" }, 2000, "easeOutBounce");
    }, "section", .8);
```

I want to be able to change easily what kind of effect I want. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit 11/09/2015:**

As @Aguardientico and @LuiGui pointed out, the problem was the scope of the $(this) inside the callback function, and I went with the @Aguardientico solution.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    function scroll_detection(the_animation, box_selector, trigger_offset ){
        var effect_offset = Math.floor($(window).height() * trigger_offset);
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            $(box_selector).each(function() {
                var post = $(this);
                var position = post.position().top - ($(window).scrollTop() + effect_offset);               
                if (position <= 0) {
                    the_animation.call(post); //Add call to give the function the right scope
                } 
            });        
        });
    }

    scroll_detection( function(){
        $(this).find(".section-title").animate( { marginLeft: "0" }, 2000, "easeOutBounce");
    }, "section", .8);
```

Comment: in scroll.detection avoid .8 and try 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue related with `scope`, you are calling `$(this)` inside your anonymous function aka `the_animation`, what if you do the following? `the_animation.call(post)`

```
function scroll_detection(the_animation, box_selector, trigger_offset ){
        var effect_offset = Math.floor($(window).height() * trigger_offset);
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            $(box_selector).each(function() {
                var post = $(this);
                var position = post.position().top - ($(window).scrollTop() + effect_offset);               
                if (position <= 0) {
                    the_animation.call(post);
                } 
            });        
        });
    }

    scroll_detection( function(){
        $(this).find(".section-title").animate( { marginLeft: "0" }, 2000, "easeOutBounce");
    }, "section", .8);
```

Comment: @EduardoSánchezHidalgoUrías please select Aguardientico's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You are function calls **DO NOT** match the function definitions.

Your parameters are **OUT OF ORDER**.

### Try this NEW CODE:

```
var scroll_detection = function scroll_detection_func(
  the_animation, box_selector, trigger_offset
){
  var effect_offset = Math.floor($(window).height() * trigger_offset);
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    $(box_selector).each(function() {
      var post = $(this);
      var position = post.position().top
                   - ($(window).scrollTop()
                   + effect_offset)
      ;               
      if (position <= 0) {
        the_animation();
      } 
    });        
  });
}

scroll_detection( 
  function(){
    $(this).find(".section-title").animate({ 
      marginLeft: "0" }, 
      2000, "easeOutBounce"
    );
  },           //the_animation
  "section",   //box_selector 
  .8           //trigger_offset
);
```

Comment: What do you mean? The order of the paramenters in scroll_detection function match the vaues on the callbacks. I don't know if thats what you mean.

Comment: `function scroll_detection(box_selector, trigger_offset, the_animation){ ... the_animation();}` & `scroll_detection("section", .8, function(){ ... }, "section", .8);` at the top of your post, doesn't match your longer code at the bottom

Comment: Try the code change - encapsulate your function in a variable, `var myFunc = function myFunc_func( ... )`.  Then call the variable as a function, `myFunc()`

Answer (score 0):

From the code you give,`the_animation` means

`$(this).find(element_selector).animate( { marginLeft: "0" }, duration, ease );`

so you can there is a `this` in your function. When you pass a function with `this` as a parameter, you need to specify what `this` mean, just try to specify the scope of `this` use `apply()`,`bind()` or 'call()' function, here are some explanations:
http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

Comment: Yeap, that was it, now it works, thank you very much for pinting in the right direction. I'll edit the code above so others can use it.